# Making textinputlayout uneditable and setting click event on it

Tags: android, android-edittext, onclicklistener, android-textinputlayout

I want to make textinputlayout uneditable by user and when user click on it i want to perform an action.
I added `android:focusable="false"` inside edittext of textinputlayout to make it uneditable but now when i click on it it is not getting callback inside onclicklistener of textinputlayout.

```
   <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/tipVideoFilePath"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/uploadVideo"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/uploadVideo">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etVideoFilePath"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dp5"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:hint="@string/videoPath"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 25):

I had the same issue for `TextInputLayout` and `TextInputEditText`. I wanted to open a dialog.
Changing the `TextInputEditText`'s "clickable" property to `true` worked for me

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/country_chooser_layout"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
    
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/country_chooser"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_expand_arrow"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:hint="Country"
        android:inputType="textCapWords" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Kotlin :

```kotlin
val countryChooser = view.findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.country_chooser)
countryChooser.setOnClickListener { v -> showCountryDialog(v) }
```

Answer (score 10):

Try this code.
get on clck listener for the edittext.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
            android:id="+id/etVideoFilePat"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:clickable="true" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 9):

1. Set `TextInputLayout` `android:clickable="true"`.
2. Set `TextInputEditText` `android:clickable="true"` and `android:focusable="false"`.
3. Set `View.OnClickListener` on both `TextInputLayout` and `TextInputEditText`.

   ```
   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_input_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="false"/>
   </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
   ```

**Note:** It's important to set `View.OnClickListener` on both views because `TextInputLayout` bigger than and behind `TextInputEditText`.

Comment: Finally something which works in this situation. Although this solution made me look fool :(

Answer (score 4):

You can try these

```
edittext.setFocusable(false);
edittext.setClickable(true);
```

Comment: For accessibility, it's preferable set `focusableInTouchMode` to false instead of `focusable`, so for instance users with keyboards can focus using 'tab' key.

Answer (score 0):

Or this:

put `EditText` in another Layout (RaltiveLayout) and make `EditText` `Match_Parent`

```
edittext.setFocusable(false);
edittext.setClickable(false);

relativelayout.setFocusable(true);
relativelayout.setClickable(true);
```

apply the onclicklistener on relativelayout

Answer (score 0):

My layout:

```html
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/tvSelectBankInputLayout"
                style="@style/MyEditText.TextInputLayout.FilledBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_16"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:hint="@string/txt_title_bank_name"
                app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_right_muiten"
                app:endIconMode="custom"
                app:errorIconDrawable="@null">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/tvSelectBank"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:cursorVisible="false"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="none"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/c_212121"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/sp_16" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

And this is my code:

```
tvSelectBank?.setOnClickListener {
    startActivityForResult(intentFor<ListBankActivity>(), REQUEST_CODE)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me (in Kotlin):

`editText.apply {
                isFocusableInTouchMode = false
                isClickable = false
                isLongClickable = false
                isEnabled = false
            }`